# How reload a model if a action emberjs 2x

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I need reload a model after a action. Look at documentation I see this http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload

But when I call reload, I receive `this.controller.get(...).reload` is not a function. How reload a model if a action, since occur this error?

```
model() {
    return this.store.peekAll('place');
},
actions: {
    reload() {
        this.controller.get('model').reload().then(function(model) {
            console.log(model);
        })
    },
}
```

Comment: could you show us some code ?

Comment: Edit with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `peekAll()` method returns a filtered array that contains all of the known records for a given type in the store.

So you can not call `reload` on a filtered array, you can do it only when you have a single record (model instance) fetched with `peekRecord(type, recordId)`;